# Saving JPEG file coming from Network Camera RTP Stream

Tags: c#, stream, jpeg, frame, rtp

I had a RTP Stream socket, receiving a JPEG Stream, from a samsung network camera.

I dont know much about how JPEG format works, but i do know that this incoming JFIF or JPEG stream is giving me the JPEG header

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   | Type-specific |              Fragment Offset                  |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |      Type     |       Q       |     Width     |     Height    |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

and then 

 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |       Restart Interval        |F|L|       Restart Count       |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

and then in the first packet, there is this header

   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |      MBZ      |   Precision   |             Length            |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    Quantization Table Data                    |
   |                              ...                              |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

I think I parsed them properly, and this is a snippet of code, how i STORE one the JPEG Stream packet.

```
    int extraOff=0;
    public bool Decode(byte* data, int offset)
    {
        if (_initialized == false)
        {
            type_specific = data[offset + 0];
            _frag[0] = data[offset + 3];
            _frag[1] = data[offset + 2];
            _frag[2] = data[offset + 1];
            _frag[3] = 0x0;
            fragment_offset = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(_frag, 0);
            jpeg_type = data[offset + 4];
            q = data[offset + 5];
            width = data[offset + 6];
            height = data[offset + 7];
            _frag[0] = data[offset + 8];
            _frag[1] = data[offset + 9];
            restart_interval = (ushort)(System.BitConverter.ToUInt16(_frag, 0) & 0x3FF);
            if (width == 0) /** elphel 333 full image size more than just one byte less that < 256 **/
                width = 256;

            byte jpegMBZ = (byte)(data[offset + 12]);
            byte jpegPrecision = (byte)(data[offset + 13]);
            int jpegLength = (int)((data[offset + 14]) * 256 + data[offset + 15]);

            byte[] tableData1 = new byte[64];
            byte[] tableData2 = new byte[64];
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
            {
                tableData1[i] = data[offset + 16 + i];
                tableData2[i] = data[offset + 16+64 + i];
            }
            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
            _offset = Utils.MakeHeaders(tmp,jpeg_type, width, height, tableData1, tableData2, 0);
            qtable = new byte[_offset];

            Array.Copy(tmp, 0, _buffer, 0, _offset);


            _initialized = true;
            tmp = null;
            GC.Collect();
            extraOff = jpegLength + 4 ;
        }
        else
        {
            _frag[0] = data[15]; //12 + 3
            _frag[1] = data[14]; //12 + 2
            _frag[2] = data[13]; //12 + 1]
            _frag[3] = 0x0;
            fragment_offset = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(_frag, 0);
            _frag[0] = data[offset + 8];
            _frag[1] = data[offset + 9];
            restart_interval = (ushort)(System.BitConverter.ToUInt16(_frag, 0) & 0x3FF);
            extraOff = 0;
        }

        return (next_fragment_offset == fragment_offset);
    }
    public unsafe bool Write(byte* data, int size, out bool sync) //Write(ref byte[] data, int size,out bool sync)
    {
        if (Decode(data, 12))
        {
            for (int i = 24 + extraOff; i < size; )
                buffer_ptr[_offset++] = data[i++];
            size -= 24+extraOff;
            next_fragment_offset += size;
            sync = true;
            return ((data[1] >> 7) == 1);
        }
        else
        {
            _initialized = false;
            _offset = qtable.Length;
            next_fragment_offset = 0;
            sync = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The problem i get is the JPEG File i successfully saved to my harddrive as a result of concatenating the JPEG streams is not showing the whole stream properly, all image previewers show the FIRST TWO incoming packet data, but leave the rest GRAY, i believe this means, the data from the third up to the last RTP packet are not parsed or saved properly.

this is the frame that i got
http://rectsoft.net/ideerge/zzz.jpg

## edited : This is how i called the Write function

```
            size = rawBuffer.Length;
            if (sync == true)
            {
                unsafe
                {
                    fixed (byte* p = rawBuffer)
                    {
                          if (_frame.Write(p, size, out sync)) //if (_frame.Write(ref _buffer, size, out sync))
                        {
                                // i save my buffer to file here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if ((rawBuffer[1] >> 7) == 1)
            {
                sync = true;
            }
```

the rawBuffer is filled by my UDP Receive function, it behaves exactly like how I handle my h264 stream and looks 100% like what I captured from WIRESHARK on VLC.

Comment: how you are controlling stream? with library or what? can you post all code starting how you connect the cam and etc?

Comment: I'm curious about the `_buffer` mentioned in the first `Array.Copy()` call -- and why are there two of those? You only `null` out `tmp`, but not `qtable`, is that intentional?

Comment: can you show code how you calling that methods??

Comment: @sarnold he is not owner of that code so he dont know any idea what that code do!

Comment: ya mekici, i dont own half of this code, but i do know all what happens in the code. that Array.Copy qtable was from someone's code, you are right, the code that i got from someone else was so messed up, and i havent cleaned it, because i just want to check if i could save the stream to a JPEG file.

Comment: I dont think there is anything wrong with my stream reader code, I wrote everything myself, and it has a RSTP, RTP and RTCP controllers to the network camera, and I can successfully decode a H264 stream.

Comment: Well, the JPEG image is definitely broken. I bet it is a result of improper concatenation. I would even say the image is good until the first concatenation point.

Comment: well.. that is why i am asking, but can anyone see what's wrong? i followed the fragment_offset to concatenate, what i am not sure is that which packet has QTable, which packet has all headers,  which packet has only the JPEG header..

Comment: I don't see anything special without having it here to debug with documentation. I only see any `restart_interval = (ushort)(System.BitConverter.ToUInt16(_frag, 0) & 0x3FF);`line which means it is Unsignet Integer and perhaps there is a fault with INT and UINT somewhere? If you want, I can step thought the debugger if you throw the stuff on my dropbox.

Comment: sure, please, but do you have a network camera?

Comment: ideerge, did you ever solve this? I am haveing exectly the same problem - the image I get appears very similar to the image you decode.

Answer (score 5):

See my implementation @ https://github.com/juliusfriedman/net7mma_core/blob/master/RtspServer/MediaTypes/RFC2435Media.cs#L58

It is much simpler then the above implementation and has a class for RtspClient and RtpClient if required

an excerpt

```
 #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes the packets to a memory stream and creates the default header and quantization tables if necessary.
        /// Assigns Image from the result
        /// </summary>
        internal virtual void ProcessPackets(bool allowLegacyPackets = false)
        {

            if (!Complete) return;

            byte TypeSpecific, Type, Quality;
            ushort Width, Height, RestartInterval = 0, RestartCount = 0;
            uint FragmentOffset;
            //A byte which is bit mapped, each bit indicates 16 bit coeffecients for the table .
            byte PrecisionTable = 0;
            ArraySegment<byte> tables = default(ArraySegment<byte>);

            Buffer = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            //Loop each packet
            foreach (RtpPacket packet in m_Packets.Values)
            {
                //Payload starts at the offset of the first PayloadOctet
                int offset = packet.NonPayloadOctets;

                if (packet.Extension) throw new NotSupportedException("RFC2035 nor RFC2435 defines extensions.");

                //Decode RtpJpeg Header

                TypeSpecific = (packet.Payload.Array[packet.Payload.Offset + offset++]);
                FragmentOffset = (uint)(packet.Payload.Array[packet.Payload.Offset + offset++] << 16 | packet.Payload.Array[packet.Payload.Offset + offset++] << 8 | packet.Payload.Array[packet.Payload.Offset + offset++]);

                #region RFC2435 -  The Type Field

                /*
                     4.1.  The Type Field

   The Type field defines the abbreviated table-specification and
   additional JFIF-style parameters not defined by JPEG, since they are
   not present in the body of the transmitted JPEG data.

   Three ranges of the type field are currently defined. Types 0-63 are
   reserved as fixed, well-known mappings to be defined by this document
   and future revisions of this document. Types 64-127 are the same as
   types 0-63, except that restart markers are present in the JPEG data
   and a Restart Marker header appears immediately following the main
   JPEG header. Types 128-255 are free to be dynamically defined by a
   session setup protocol (which is beyond the scope of this document).

   Of the first group of fixed mappings, types 0 and 1 are currently
   defined, along with the corresponding types 64 and 65 that indicate
   the presence of restart markers.  They correspond to an abbreviated
   table-specification indicating the "Baseline DCT sequential" mode,
   8-bit samples, square pixels, three components in the YUV color
   space, standard Huffman tables as defined in [1, Annex K.3], and a
   single interleaved scan with a scan component selector indicating
   components 1, 2, and 3 in that order.  The Y, U, and V color planes
   correspond to component numbers 1, 2, and 3, respectively.  Component
   1 (i.e., the luminance plane) uses Huffman table number 0 and
   quantization table number 0 (defined below) and components 2 and 3
   (i.e., the chrominance planes) use Huffman table number 1 and
   quantization table number 1 (defined below).

   Type numbers 2-5 are reserved and SHOULD NOT be used.  Applications
   based on previous versions of this document (RFC 2035) should be
   updated to indicate the presence of restart markers with type 64 or
   65 and the Restart Marker header.

   The two RTP/JPEG types currently defined are described below:

                            horizontal   vertical   Quantization
           types  component samp. fact. samp. fact. table number
         +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
         |       |  1 (Y)  |     2     |     1     |     0     |
         | 0, 64 |  2 (U)  |     1     |     1     |     1     |
         |       |  3 (V)  |     1     |     1     |     1     |
         +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
         |       |  1 (Y)  |     2     |     2     |     0     |
         | 1, 65 |  2 (U)  |     1     |     1     |     1     |
         |       |  3 (V)  |     1     |     1     |     1     |
         +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

   These sampling factors indicate that the chrominance components of
   type 0 video is downsampled horizontally by 2 (often called 4:2:2)
   while the chrominance components of type 1 video are downsampled both
   horizontally and vertically by 2 (often called 4:2:0).

   Types 0 and 1 can be used to carry both progressively scanned and
   interlaced image data.  This is encoded using the Type-specific field
   in the main JPEG header.  The following values are defined:

      0 : Image is progressively scanned.  On a computer monitor, it can
          be displayed as-is at the specified width and height.

      1 : Image is an odd field of an interlaced video signal.  The
          height specified in the main JPEG header is half of the height
          of the entire displayed image.  This field should be de-
          interlaced with the even field following it such that lines
          from each of the images alternate.  Corresponding lines from
          the even field should appear just above those same lines from
          the odd field.

      2 : Image is an even field of an interlaced video signal.

      3 : Image is a single field from an interlaced video signal, but
          it should be displayed full frame as if it were received as
          both the odd & even fields of the frame.  On a computer
          monitor, each line in the image should be displayed twice,
          doubling the height of the image.
                     */

                #endregion

                Type = (packet.Payload.Array[packet.Payload.Offset + offset++]);

                //Check for a RtpJpeg Type of less than 5 used in RFC2035 for which RFC2435 is the errata
                if (!allowLegacyPackets && Type >= 2 && Type <= 5)
                {
                    //Should allow for 2035 decoding seperately
                    throw new ArgumentException("Type numbers 2-5 are reserved and SHOULD NOT be used.  Applications based on RFC 2035 should be updated to indicate the presence of restart markers with type 64 or 65 and the Restart Marker header.");
                }

                Quality = packet.Payload.Array[packet.Payload.Offset + offset++];
                Width = (ushort)(packet.Payload.Array[packet.Payload.Offset + offset++] * 8);// in 8 pixel multiples
                Height = (ushort)(packet.Payload.Array[packet.Payload.Offset + offset++] * 8);// in 8 pixel multiples
                //It is worth noting Rtp does not care what you send and more tags such as comments and or higher resolution pictures may be sent and these values will simply be ignored.

                //Restart Interval 64 - 127
                if (Type > 63 && Type < 128)
                {
                    /*
                       This header MUST be present immediately after the main JPEG header
                       when using types 64-127.  It provides the additional information
                       required to properly decode a data stream containing restart markers.

                        0                   1                   2                   3
                        0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
                       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
                       |       Restart Interval        |F|L|       Restart Count       |
                       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
                     */
                    RestartInterval = (ushort)(packet.Payload.Array[packet.Payload.Offset + offset++] << 8 | packet.Payload.Array[packet.Payload.Offset + offset++]);
                    RestartCount = (ushort)((packet.Payload.Array[packet.Payload.Offset + offset++] << 8 | packet.Payload.Array[packet.Payload.Offset + offset++]) & 0x3fff);
                }

                // A Q value of 255 denotes that the  quantization table mapping is dynamic and can change on every frame.
                // Decoders MUST NOT depend on any previous version of the tables, and need to reload these tables on every frame.
                if (/*FragmentOffset == 0 || */Buffer.Position == 0)
                {

                    //RFC2435 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2435#section-3.1.8
                    //3.1.8.  Quantization Table header
                    /*
                     This header MUST be present after the main JPEG header (and after the
                        Restart Marker header, if present) when using Q values 128-255.  It
                        provides a way to specify the quantization tables associated with
                        this Q value in-band.
                     */
                    if (Quality == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("(Q)uality = 0 is Reserved.");
                    else if (Quality >= 100)
                    {

                        /* https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2435#section-3.1.8
                         * Quantization Table Header
                         * -------------------------
                         0                   1                   2                   3
                         0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
                        +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
                        |      MBZ      |   Precision   |             Length            |
                        +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
                        |                    Quantization Table Data                    |
                        |                              ...                              |
                        +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
                         */

                        if ((packet.Payload.Array[packet.Payload.Offset + offset++]) != 0)
                        {
                            //Must Be Zero is Not Zero
                            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                        }

                        //Read the PrecisionTable (notes below)
                        PrecisionTable = (packet.Payload.Array[packet.Payload.Offset + offset++]);

                        #region RFC2435 Length Field

                        /*
                                 
                                    The Length field is set to the length in bytes of the quantization
                                    table data to follow.  The Length field MAY be set to zero to
                                    indicate that no quantization table data is included in this frame.
                                    See section 4.2 for more information.  If the Length field in a
                                    received packet is larger than the remaining number of bytes, the
                                    packet MUST be discarded.

                                    When table data is included, the number of tables present depends on
                                    the JPEG type field.  For example, type 0 uses two tables (one for
                                    the luminance component and one shared by the chrominance
                                    components).  Each table is an array of 64 values given in zig-zag
                                    order, identical to the format used in a JFIF DQT marker segment.

                             * PrecisionTable *
                             
                                    For each quantization table present, a bit in the Precision field
                                    specifies the size of the coefficients in that table.  If the bit is
                                    zero, the coefficients are 8 bits yielding a table length of 64
                                    bytes.  If the bit is one, the coefficients are 16 bits for a table
                                    length of 128 bytes.  For 16 bit tables, the coefficients are
                                    presented in network byte order.  The rightmost bit in the Precision
                                    field (bit 15 in the diagram above) corresponds to the first table
                                    and each additional table uses the next bit to the left.  Bits beyond
                                    those corresponding to the tables needed by the type in use MUST be
                                    ignored.
                                 
                                 */

                        #endregion

                        //Length of all tables
                        ushort Length = (ushort)(packet.Payload.Array[packet.Payload.Offset + offset++] << 8 | packet.Payload.Array[packet.Payload.Offset + offset++]);

                        //If there is Table Data Read it from the payload, Length should never be larger than 128 * tableCount
                        if (Length == 0 && Quality == byte.MaxValue) throw new InvalidOperationException("RtpPackets MUST NOT contain Q = 255 and Length = 0.");
                        else  if (Length > packet.Payload.Count - offset) //If the indicated length is greater than that of the packet taking into account the offset
                            continue; // The packet must be discarded
                        
                        //Copy the tables present
                        tables = new ArraySegment<byte>(packet.Payload.Array, packet.Payload.Offset + offset, (int)Length);
                        offset += (int)Length;
                    }
                    else // Create them from the given Quality parameter ** Duality (Unify Branch)
                    {
                        tables = new ArraySegment<byte>(CreateQuantizationTables(Type, Quality, PrecisionTable));
                    }

                    //Write the JFIF Header after reading or generating the QTables
                    byte[] header = CreateJFIFHeader(Type, Width, Height, tables, PrecisionTable, RestartInterval);
                    Buffer.Write(header, 0, header.Length);
                }

                //Write the Payload data from the offset
                Buffer.Write(packet.Payload.Array, packet.Payload.Offset + offset, packet.Payload.Count - (offset + packet.PaddingOctets));
            }

            //Check for EOI Marker and write if not found
            if (Buffer.Position == Buffer.Length || Buffer.ReadByte() != JpegMarkers.EndOfInformation)
            {
                Buffer.WriteByte(JpegMarkers.Prefix);
                Buffer.WriteByte(JpegMarkers.EndOfInformation);
            }

            //Create the Image form the Buffer
            Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Buffer);
        }
```

Comment: Any chance you could Update the link?